# Is it better to match the tense in this case

Tags: present-perfect

As you have cancelled my order ,don't change anything .But if you can let me know why you **cancelled** it that would be nice .

What do you think of the use of past simple is it justified? I think so because 
 for the second cancelled  I don't mind if it has an effect on the present where as in the first one it has a present relevance, but may be it is better to use the same tense for both (past simple or present perfect) as it is the same action

Comment: Why are you asking? The order was cancelled. Very simple. Why confuse the issue?

Comment: because I thought and may be still thinking  that for the same action only one tense is possible in this case either past simple or present perfect but not present perfect and after past simple

Comment: Beyond the actual grammar, which must be correct, there is the issue of what you *want to say*. :)

Comment: What are you actually asking? Since the only word you put in bold is the second use of *cancelled* are you suggesting it should be something different than what it is? If so, what? Are you suggesting there's something wrong with the sentence as it's written?

Comment: yes just would like to know if past simple for the second use of the verb  cancel is right in the last sentence as the first one is present perfect and it is the same action at the same time

Answer (score -1):

If you want to emphasize the present relevance, use the present perfect. If you want to focus on the past action, the cancellation took place in the past, use the past simple. I don't see anything wrong with using different tenses in the same sentence.

Comment: even if it is the same action

Comment: This is common also with news: a news fact is introduced with present perfect and further details are given with past simple. For example: " The famous actor so and so has died. He died last night of a cardiac arrest.

Comment: why downvote for this answer

Comment: I would like to know as well, what is wrong with my answer? Downvoting like this is completely useless.